# PIC:how can we operate PIC24FJ256GB106 controller to 32MHz internal frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, frequency, crystal

I am using below configuration bits for 32MHz internal frequency.

_CONFIG2(IESO_OFF & FCKSM_CSECME  & OSCIOFNC_ON  & POSCMOD_NONE  & **FNOSC_FRCPLL**)

I know that **FNOSC_FRCPLL** give me 32MHz frequency but I am getting only 8MHz frequency.

Is that any configuration which am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to that, you may have to set the `OSCCON` register to an appropriate value.

From the page 123 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39897c.pdf):

[image]

Also, have a look at page 122 and other pages that may include information about this.

Comment: I have already setting OSCCON register with 0x1100 for FRCPLL but i am not getting right frequecy.Can you give me right example with coding?